# Which hotel information should you provide when travelling to the US?

Tags: visas, air-travel, usa, proof-of-accommodation

When flying to the US they ask which hotel you are going to stay in. If you plan to stay the first night in one hotel and then move to another for the rest of the time, which hotel details are you meant to include? There is never space for more than one hotel in the form . The form also  doesn't ask for the "first night", rather just for the name of address of the hotel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recall that the the form itself includes instructions staying that you should give the address of the hotel where you stay first.  However, current versions of the form apparently do not say this.

I may remember this from an older version of the form, or I may have seen it on form I-94 or I-94W.

It probably doesn't matter much.  If you can't get a definitive answer, you can always leave the address blank until you get to the booth, and ask the border guard what address he wants you to use.  Or, in light of Willeke's comment, fill out two forms, and ask the officer which one to use.

As it appears that you are giving data to your airline, have you asked them which address to use?

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. In my case I have to fill a web form supplied by my airline where I didn't see any instructions of this sort.  Presumably they then forward the information on.

Comment: @eleanora my original answer appears to have been incorrect.  Please look at the edited answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Do NOT leave the space empty. I was send to the end of the line (and it was long) because I had not filled out all lines on the form. Better ask one of the guards before you join the waiting line.

Comment: @Willeke thanks.  I've edited the answer to take this into account.

Comment: Be careful with having two forms on you - this might look suspicous. I accidentally handed in an empty form and they made a huge deal out of why I had two forms on me.

Comment: @Al-Muhandis how did you get out of it?  I would have said "I took an extra in case I made a mistake."  It seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: I did email the airline but got an incomprehensible reply suggesting I call them instead.